# How to cast the passed Hierarchical URI extra?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, casting, uri

My app has an intent filter that allows another app to pass data via 'share' and the intent extras are following (found out by iterating over

```
Intent.getExtras()):

android.intent.extra.SUBJECT some string (java.lang.String)


android.intent.extra.STREAM content://provider/resource (android.net.Uri$HierarchicalUri)
```

I need to copy the file from the URI given as `Intent.EXTRA_STREAM`, however, there's no way to obtain it with `Intent.get<type name>Extra()`, and if I try to pick it up with `Intent.getExtras().get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)`, it doesn't help, cause I don't know how to cast it to the 'normal' URI, casting to URI class causes `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, I've resolved this problem.

Actually, I tried to cast to `java.net.URI` instead of `android.net.Uri`,
Android's `Uri` seem to make some difference of Java's `URI`.

```
intent.getExtras.get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM) instanceof URI // false
intent.getExtras.get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM) instanceof Uri // true
```

That's the point.